# Install freetds on Heroku

Tags: heroku, freetds, tiny-tds

I'm looking for a step by step guide, how to install freetds on Heroku. I need to access Sql Server from ruby script, and unfortunately Cedar doesn't support tinytds gem out of box. I've read whatever information there is available on internet, including about heroku buildpacks but was unable to succeed.

I would be very grateful to whoever can help to deploy freetds on heroku.

Thanks in advance,
 - Jack

Comment: You will need to make a build pack that adds all of the required binaries is just using a gemfile does not work. (look here for help on buildpacks https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpack-binaries)

Answer (score 1):

Try [tiny_tds](https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/tiny_tds) which works for me out of the box on Cedar + Rails 3. It has [a native compilation pass](https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/tiny_tds/blob/master/tasks/ports.rake) which bundles FreeTDS in.